# confusion regarding array.average() functionality in "var avg = array.average()"

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Cheers guys. I was asked to make this code work in a learning challenge and I'm not sure how to tackle the "array.average()" part, as it's not a function.

What I was asked was this:

```
var array = [5,44,23,11,55,68];
var avg = array.average();
console.log(avg);
```

So far, I've tackled the averaging of the array like this:

```
function average(){
 var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   total += array[i];
  }
 var avg = total / array.length;
}
```

Any and all corrections are welcome. This is 100% learning based so everything helps.

Comment: I guess you want to add the average function to the Array prototype

Comment: Mind explaining it a bit further? You're probably on the money tho.

EDIT: I actually googled just that. So I should write something on the lines of function array (5,44,23,11,55,68), right?
Or should it be function array (){ this.5 and so on?

Comment: [javascript prototype documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) does a better job and explaining prototypes than I ever could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attach the function to your array object, and then make sure to return a value at the end of it:

```js
var array = [5,44,23,11,55,68];
array.average = () => {
 var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   total += array[i];
  }
 var avg = total / array.length;
 return avg;
}

var avg = array.average();
console.log(avg);
```

(avoid mutating native prototypes)

Comment: I found this one to be the cleanest way, but how does it differ from the prototype options? Is it the same/simmilar?

Comment: Mutating native prototypes is pretty much universally considered to be terrible practice - it's what got us the [smoosh controversy](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap/pull/56). It's better to set the custom function on your object, or, even better, to make a *wrapper* around the object and give the wrapper an `average` method. (it's just fine to mutate objects/classes you create yourself)

Comment: BTW, *Array.prototype* is more correctly referred to as a [*built-in* object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects).  The term "native object" was last defined in [*ECMAScript 2011 (ed. 5)*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.6) and included built-in objects and others that might be created by javascript code, so in `var a = {}`, then *a* is a native object. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you need to add it in the Array.prototype (which is a bad idea), use `Object.defineProperty` to add it in as non-enumerable and won't clash with other native methods:

```js
var array = [5,44,23,11,55,68];

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'average', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: () => array.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / array.length
});

console.log(array.average())
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `average` function to `Array.prototype`:

```js
var arr = [5,44,23,11,55,68];

Array.prototype.average = function() { 
  return this.reduce(function(acc, cur) { return (acc + cur); }, 0) / this.length;
}

var avg = arr.average();
console.log(avg);
```